# Per application VPN settings

Tags: network, vpn

I use a VPN tunnel to connect to a remote network on Snow Leopard. I set it up with the system settings for VPN and it works fine. Unfortunately, the VPN tunnel is used for all connections. Some ports (like the one I use for IMAP) are not open in the remote network.

Can I use VPN for some applications (like Firefox and Terminal) and my regular connection for others? Is there a third party app to fine tune the VPN settings?

Cheers

Comment: If it´s only about Firefox and Terminal, have you considered using SSH and a SSH-Proxy instead of VPN (if possible)?

Comment: I have considered that. For the sake of security, a direct SSH connection is not possible.

Comment: How are you using the VPN connection? I mean if you only access certain hosts, then I might have a solution..

Comment: I use it for the Terminal (SSH), Firefox (I need it only to access scientific journals via my institutes network) and CyberDuck. I access many hosts, both local and remote. I'm curious, what would be your solution?

Comment: @emempe in which way do you think a VPN connection will be more secure than a SSH one? SSH would cover your Terminal sessions, could create a Proxy for Firefox (FoxyProxy would make that super-easy) and CyberDuck can use SFTP. All this doesn´t require a VPN than re-routes all of your network traffic in my opinion.

Comment: @Asmus: This is not my decision, our network admin prefers VPN, so I have to live with that. No direct SSH, period.

Comment: @emempe then maybe it´s time to tell your network admin that tunnelling IMAP through VPN is a not-so-brilliant idea ;-)

Comment: @Asmus: He won't listen. Some more details WHY it's not so brilliant would be helpful :) Do maybe have an idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: At least with cisco ASAs the admin can enforce wether or not to allow split tunneling.  If the network you're vpn'ing into is on 10/8 then a split tunnel is a routing config that forces all traffic to 10/8 over the VPN and all other traffic goes over the regular network.  The administrator can force the client to push all traffic over the VPN.  This is a "good thing" prevents someone from poping your home network and gaining access to the corp network.  That said, it's defeat-able by setting up your own routing with the route command.

Comment: Also, VPN is not necessarily more secure than ssh, but it's a ton easier to manage.  One entry point vs. lots of entry points.  Control over who is accessing it.  The person running the VPN is likely not the person admin'ing your desktop.

Comment: @scarface Good to know ... doesn't really help me though.

Comment: @emempe the point is that you can set yourself up to route some traffic over the vpn and some traffic not over the vpn. Ask you admin about allowing a split tunnel.  There should be a setting in your VPN software that allows you to have only the traffic that needs the VPN go over the vpn.

Comment: @skarface There is no option in the Snow Leopard VPN settings to route only specific traffic over VPN. That is exactly what I was aksing. HOW can I do that with Snow Leopard or with a third party app?

Comment: @emempe There are options that allow you to only route specific traffic over VPN.  You have to adjust your routing table (man route) to do so.  Some of this is done automatically when you establish your VPN connection.  If your home network is in 192.168.1.0/24 space and the network you VPN into is in 10.0.0.0/8 space, all traffic destined to 10/8 is automatically sent over the VPN. All other traffic would go to your default route. This is the split in split-tunnel.  Traffic can go to 192 or to 10.  Without split tunnel traffic only goes to 10 (via the VPN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the network settings are global, and apply to the whole machine, including all applications.

VPNs will work great to access machines on a known network (eg: 192.168.1.x = home, 
10.1.1.x = work via VPN)

What kind of VPN is it? It's possible that the VPN has grabbed the default route, meaning that all network traffic that isn't on your local network will go via the VPN.

You can run `netstat -nr` in Terminal to see your routing table.

You can use `sudo route change default 10.1.1.1` to change the default route to your local network's router (eg 10.1.1.1 for me) so that it will route external connections. Connections to your VPN network should still go through the VPN.

Hopefully this helps!